# jar file building

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-6.9, executable-jar

My program runs fine under NetBean. So I tried to build a jar file. I set everything up with project properties and picked the Main class by "browsing the Main class" so that I do not make any typing mistakes. Everything seems fine and a jar file is generated. But the jar file just could not run after showing the SlashScreen. The program keeps saying there is no main class but it is right there in the class!  I checked the MANIFEST.MF file, Main-Class is set just right there too. It really confused me. What could be wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you build your jar wrong? Package/directory hierarchy wrong? Impossible to tell w/o more info.

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running the class file that has your main function (no jar)?

Comment: How did you build the jar file and how are you running it?

Comment: unzip your jar and verify all the classes are infect there and in correct order .Since you are seeing splash I suggest putting some logging there to see whats happening.

Comment: I can run the program with the 'run' button/command in NetBean project and the Main Class.